# Using simple linear regression for multiple classification task

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a language classification dataset with 22000 entries, 1000 for each of 22 languages.
Can someone please advise how could I write classification model using simple linear regression, so it would be not one model picking of 0, 1, 2, … 22 values, but it would be 22 models picking between 1 and 0 (correct and incorrect). How is better to rewrite my y target?

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/KseniaGiansar/AMA/raw/9109fd16d2cafcc25b2f5ee4373ca19dabe76a67/df_languages.csv')
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['language']= label_encoder.fit_transform(df['language'])
x = np.array(df['Text'])
y = np.array(df['language'])
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(x)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=3)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing one-vs-rest (OvR) multiclass classification. To be able to do this, you need to one-hot-encode the column `"language"` and then iterate over the new columns fitting one column for each dummy-column:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/KseniaGiansar/AMA/raw/9109fd16d2cafcc25b2f5ee4373ca19dabe76a67/df_languages.csv')

# One-hot encoding
y = pd.get_dummies(df['language'])

print(y.columns.tolist())

x = np.array(df['Text'])
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(x)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=3)

# You'll now have 22 models, one for each language
models = []
scores = []
for language in y.columns:
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train[language])
    score = model.score(X_test, y_test[language])
    models.append(model)
    scores.append(score)

# Now, 'scores' is a list of R^2 scores of the models
for language, score in zip(y.columns, scores):
    print(f"Model for language '{language}' R^2 score: {score}")
```

This works, but I advise you to use `LogisticRegression` instead of `LinearRegression`, because `LinearRegression` is not bound the values `0` and `1`.

Use `LogisticRegression` instead. It will only estimate `0` and `1`, i.e. is it that specific language or not. Additionally you can calculate the probabilities if it is that specific language or not.

Instead of fitting multiple models, you could wrap your classifier with [`OneVsRestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html).

Comment: thank you so much for this! Can I please ask, if I want to get each model’s score or confusion matrix, what is the way to do it?
When  I tried 
`for model in models: print(model.score(X_test, y_test))`
It raises 
`ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (22!=1)`